# How do I get a plot to estimate the performance of my algorithm?

Tags: java, c, algorithm, plot

like the plots in:
http://www.cs.berkeley.edu/~ballard/cs267.sp11/hw1/results/

Using some statistics tool(such as R, matlab) could achieve this, but it is not convinent enough.

I mainly use C, java and python for algorithm implementation.

Comment: Google for C, Java and Python graphics libraries and tools.  The Internet is awash with them.

Comment: Whatever you do, for the love of mathematics, do not pass a degree 14 polynomial through your points!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made tool to benchmark algorithms/implementations in Scala, which is compatible with Java, but maybe not that easy to understand for a newcomer (1st code) https://gist.github.com/1152783 .

But if you generate data like in the first comment, and a plot command like in the second for gnuplot with Java, Python or something else, you can produce a graph like this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/8165158/312172 (it isn't the graph for the data on the code page, but with the same tool).

Answer (score 1):

[Caliper](http://code.google.com/p/caliper/) is really good at measuring the performance of Java programs, and generates nice plots in a cute web interface.  (You can see examples on its home page, both of how to write a benchmark, and of the plots it generates.)

Answer (score 1):

[valgrind](http://valgrind.org/) and [oprofile](http://oprofile.sourceforge.net/) for profiling  the c code. If you want to dig deep, [systemtap](http://sourceware.org/systemtap) helps.

[Gnuplot](http://www.gnuplot.info/) is a tool for drawing graphs.