# How to merge tuples by same elements in Scala

Tags: list, scala, tuples, slick

For example, if I have the following tuples:

```
(1, "a", "l")
(1, "a", "m")
(1, "a", "n")
```

I want to merge them like this:

```
(1, "a", List("l", "m", "n"))
```

In my case, the lists are a result from an inner join using Slick.
So, the first and second elements (`1` and `"a"`) should be the same.
If somebody knows how to merge like that in case of using Slick, let me know please.

Or more generally, the way to merge tuples with inner lists by the same elements.

```
(1, "a", "l")
(1, "a", "m")
(1, "b", "n")
(1, "b", "o")
// to like this
List( (1, "a", List("l", "m")), (1, "b", List("n", "o")) )
```

Comment: What result do you expect if you have a case with (1, "a", "m") and (2, "a", "l") tuples?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

How about:

```
val l = ??? // Your list

val groups = l groupBy { case (a, b, c) => (a,b) }

val tups = groups map { case ((a,b), l) => (a,b,l.map(_._3)) }

tups.toList
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try `foldRight`

```
val l = List((1, "a", "l"), (1, "a", "m"), (1, "a", "n"), (1, "b", "n"), (1, "b", "o"))
val exp = List((1, "a", List("l", "m", "n")), (1, "b", List("n", "o")))

val result = l.foldRight(List.empty[(Int, String, List[String])]) {
  (x, acc) =>
    val (n, s1, s2) = x

    acc match {
      case (n_, s1_, l_) :: t if (n == n_ && s1 == s1_) =>
        (n_, s1_, (s2 :: l_)) :: t

      case _ =>
        (n, s1, List(s2)) :: acc

    }
}

println(result)
println(result == exp)
```

*Update*

If the input list is not sorted:

```
val result = l.sorted.foldRight(...)
```

Comment: This will only work is all the tuples are sorted like the above example. Had the four tuples been arranged in different way, then this solution wont match

Comment: The data comes from a database, so it should be sorted by the database. Anyway, just in case, I've added an update.

Comment: I learned from your code. but gzm0's answer is more generally I think. btw thank you @Beryllium .

Comment: You're welcome, that's OK. I agree that it's a more general way. If you have a large number of rows, and you sort sooner or later anyway, there is always `foldRight`. [That](http://stackoverflow.com/q/8160037/2390083) might be of interest, this is where I learned about `foldRight`.